# Как спавнить объекты через массив?

Tags: c#, unity3d

В общем я немного баклажан, и не могу кое чего понять

У меня есть список gameObject'ов , это спавнеры(просто пустые объекты, от них мне нужна только позиция)

И в общем мне нужно заспавнить префабы нпс на каждом из этих объектов(их всего 10 в листе)

Я не могу понять как именно мне это сделать

Заранее спасибо за любую помощь.

Comment: А как пробовали и как именно оно не работает? Покажите код вашей попытки.

Comment: Не пробовал никак ещё, я за этим сб и пришел, совета просить, в документации ничего такого не нашел

Comment: просто обходите этот список спавнеров и спавните там персонажей

Comment: Как именно его обойти? Я не понимаю от слова совсем в этом , может есть документации? Просто все что я нашел это создание листа и добавление в него чисел

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/iteration-statements

Comment: Если не знаете, как обойти ("перебрать" каждый элемент) массив - Вам в первую очередь необходимо изучить основы C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам в этом поможет один из методов класса Object - [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html). Посмотрите его реализацию и примеры в документации.